# WP get posts with no custom field value

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'epost',
    'post_status' => 'future,publish',
    'meta_key' => 'custorder',
    'orderby'=>'meta_value',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'posts_per_page' => 900
);
```

But I can't get the posts on which the `custorder` value is not set. How can I retrieve those posts also?

Comment: by "empty" do you mean an empty string `""` or not set at all?

Comment: try this .. $myquery = new WP_Query("post_type=epost&meta_key=custorder&meta_value=$metaValue&order=ASC" );

Comment: I mean, not set at all. What is $metaValue ?

Comment: if you have any  meta value then you can pass into array otherwise you should leave blank it.

Comment: You"ll need a full `meta_query` with an array which calls posts with the desired custom field key, and one array which calls posts where the custom field key does not exists

Comment: aham, something like making two WP_Query(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query with a proper `meta_query`

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'epost',
    'post_status'    => ['future','publish'],
    'meta_key'       => 'custorder',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 900,
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'     => 'custorder',
            'compare' => 'EXIST'
        ],
        [    
            'key'     => 'custorder',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: The meta_query array should contain 'relation' => 'OR' as relation is 'AND' by default. The key cannot EXIST and NOT EXIST at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is the best solution but I've found a workaround

```
$query1 = new WP_Query($args1);
$query2 = new WP_Query($args2);
$the_query = new WP_Query();
$the_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );
$the_query->post_count = $query1->post_count + $query2->post_count;
```

to match two different arguments into one query. For the first set of arguments I've used `'meta_key'=>'custorder'` and for the second one I've added `'meta_compare'=>'NOT EXISTS'`

Answer (score 0):

So to find posts of type `epost` which does not have a meta field with key `custorder` assigned:

```
    $metaKey = 'custorder';
    $postType = 'epost';

    $args = [
        'post_type'      => $postType,
        'meta_query'     => [
            [
                'key'     => $metaKey,
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key' => 'custorder',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '='
            )
          ),
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: It just displays nothing... And I've do checked the codex but I can't handle it

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to replicate your situation, but have you tried to use `var_dump($variable);` to see if the post really has the `custorder meta_key`?

Comment: well, It should not have it, because as I said above, by empty I mean not set at all :)

Comment: In that case, instead of sorting posts on `meta_key`, how about sorting on `post_type`?

Comment: well I need to order all the posts ( with that certain post type "epost") by an input(number) field, How can I do that way?

Comment: what's the name of the "input(number) field"? Is this a metakey?

Comment: Your post_status is wrong btw. it should be `'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' ),`

Comment: You can't sort post based on meta_key, if you want posts to show without this specific metakey. Unfortunately, you post_type doesn't create the metakey with an empty value if no value is selected. There might be a workaround. Can you make a screenshot of your post_type wp admin menu? If your `post_type` uses `taxonomy`, you can use that to sort posts instead.